# PHP Create a Tree view using two tables

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, treeview

**i have two mysql tables**

```
  1. questions
  2. answers
```

**the question table has question and answer table has related answers 
each answer point to a question so it has levels**

ex

```
question 1 -> answer 1 -> question 2
           -> answer 2 -> question 3
           -> answer 3 -> question 4 -> answer 1 -> question 5
                                     -> answer 2 -> question 6
                                     -> answer 3 -> question 7
question 8 -> answer 1 -> question 9
           -> answer 2 -> question 10-> answer 1 ->question 12
                                        answer 2 ->question 13
           -> answer 3 -> question 11
```

**i need to show questions as tree view**

ex

```
question 1->question2
            question3
            question4->question 5
                       question 6
                       question 7
question 8->question 9
            question 10->question 12
                         question 13
            question 11
```

**my question table fields are**

```
id  qtype   qtext
```

**my answeres table fields are**

```
id  answer  quzid   targetquz
```

Anyone know how to create a treeview using php based on this two tables. thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Hope I'm not misunderstanding things here (not sure if you have intentionally question pointing to answer then to another question without any answer); but generally speaking I would use `while` loop.

`while()`
`{
first level here`
`while()`
     `{
     second level here`
        `while()`
          `{
           third level here`
           `....`
`}`
`}`
`}`

Comment: there are no levels defined on table, each has dynamic relationship